# Update Hyperlink Field via Powershell (assembly missing)

Tags: powershell, assembly-references

I simply want to update a hyperlink field via Powershell:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
.
.
.
$newPTH = $newBaseURL + $filenameSTR;
$linkOBJ = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue
$linkOBJ.Url = $newPTH
$linkOBJ.Description = $itemOBJ['Product_x0020_Specification'].Description
$itemOBJ['Product_x0020_Specification'] = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUrlValue] $linkOBJ;
```

But I've got the problem that PowerShell won't find the corresponding assembly

> Cannot find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue]

Which assembly do I have to add for that Class?
thx

Comment: what version of CSOM are you using ? Is it onprem or online ?

Comment: It's SharePoint 2016 on prem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to replace Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue with Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUrlValue**

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
$newPTH = $newBaseURL + $filenameSTR;
$linkOBJ = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUrlValue
$linkOBJ.Url = $newPTH
$linkOBJ.Description = 
$itemOBJ['Product_x0020_Specification'].Description
$itemOBJ['Product_x0020_Specification'] = 
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUrlValue] $linkOBJ;
```

Comment: As you are working with Microsoft.SharePoint.Client (CSOM)and Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue is from (SSOM) Microsoft.SharePoint

Comment: You made my day! :-)